# Angular - Type 'Void[]' is not assignable to type 'FilterExpression[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to have both of these statements inside this map, one will be able to get the operator that I need, and the other with push the values. I'm very confused on why i'm getting this specific error. It is erroring out on the "this.DataSourceFilters"

```
Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'FilterExpression[]'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'FilterExpression'.ts(2322



DataSourceFilters: Array<FilterExpression>;
constructor(filterDefinitionModel?: FilterDefinitionModel) {
 if (filterDefinitionModel.DataSourceFilters) {
        this.DataSourceFilters = filterDefinitionModel.DataSourceFilters.map(
           (filter) => {
              const fe = new FilterExpression(this.logicalOperator);
               fe.FilterOptions.push(new FilterOption(filter.PropertyPath, filter.FilterOperation, filter.Values));

           }
           
              // f.PropertyPath, f.FilterOperation, f.Values
        );
     }
```

Comment: the function passed to `map` doesn't return anything, so you get an array of `void`. Just return the type of data expected in `this.DataSourceFilters` or don't use `map`.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your function contained in map, you can add `return fe`.

I see people get confused with lambdas pretty often. If you were doing something like `map(filter => new FilterExpression(this.logicalOperator))`, this syntax would automatically return the filter expression. Since you needed to perform an extra step, you'll need to explicitly return something.